# Method is outputting incorrect value?

Tags: java, methods, code-duplication

So I'm working on an assignment that is trying to output the energy consumption of appliances within a house. I have created an `Appliance` called `ElectricCooker` and an `Appliance` called `ElectricShower`. They both have exactly the same code apart from different variable names yet some how produce different outputs.

Here is the relevant code: (Sorry about the amount of code, this reproduces the program)

**ElectricCooker**

```
public class ElectricCooker extends Appliance
{

    public int isOn = -1;
    public int isOff = 0;
    public int incrementTime;
    public int varPass = -1;

     @Override
     public int currentState()
    {

        if (varPass == 0)
        return isOff;
        else
        {
            return isOn;
        }
        //returns isOn;
}

     @Override
        public void useTime(int defaultTime)
        {

            defaultTime = 15;
            incrementTime = 4;

        }

         public void cook()
        {
            //add code
        }

    @Override
         public void timePasses()
         {

             if(varPass == isOff)
                 varPass = 0;
             else
             {

             ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(electricityUse);  
             ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(5);     
             int getCookerConsumed = ElectricMeter.getInstance().getElectricityUsed();

             System.out.println("Electric cooker electricity consumption = " + getCookerConsumed);

             }

         }


    ElectricCooker(int electricityUse, int gasUse, int waterUse, int timeOn)  
{
    super(electricityUse, gasUse, waterUse, timeOn);

    this.electricityUse = 5 * incrementTime;
    this.gasUse = 0 * incrementTime;
    this.waterUse = 0 * incrementTime;
    this.timeOn = 15 * incrementTime;

} 

}
```

**ElectricShower**

```
public class ElectricShower extends Appliance
{

    public int isOn = -1;
    public int isOff = 0;
    public int incrementTime;
    public int varPass = -1;

     @Override
     public int currentState()
    {

        if (varPass == 0)
        return isOff;
        else
        {
            return isOn;
        }
        //returns isOn;
}

     @Override
        public void useTime(int defaultTime)
        {

            defaultTime = 15;
            incrementTime = 4;

        }

    @Override
         public void timePasses()
         {

             if(varPass == isOff)
                 varPass = 0;
             else
             {

             ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(electricityUse);  
             ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(5);     
             int getShowerConsumed = ElectricMeter.getInstance().getElectricityUsed();

             System.out.println("Electric shower electricity consumption = " + getShowerConsumed);

             }

         }


    ElectricShower(int electricityUse, int gasUse, int waterUse, int timeOn)  
{
    super(electricityUse, gasUse, waterUse, timeOn);

    this.electricityUse = 5 * incrementTime;
    this.gasUse = 0 * incrementTime;
    this.waterUse = 0 * incrementTime;
    this.timeOn = 15 * incrementTime;

} 

}
```

**Appliance**

```
abstract public class Appliance 
{
    public int varPass;
    public int isOn;
    public int isOff;
    public int electricityUse, gasUse, waterUse, timeOn;


     public abstract void useTime(int defaultTime);

     public int currentState()
    {

        if (varPass == 0)
        return isOff;
        else
        {
            return isOn;
        }

        //returns isOn;
}
    public abstract void timePasses();

Appliance(int electricityUse,int gasUse,int waterUse,int timeOn) 
{
    electricityUse = 0;
    gasUse = 0;
    waterUse = 0;
    timeOn = 0; 
}

}
```

**ElectricMeter**

```
public class ElectricMeter 
{
    ElectricMeter() {}
private static ElectricMeter instance = new ElectricMeter();
public static ElectricMeter getInstance() { return instance; }

private int electricityUsed = 0;
public void incrementConsumed(int value)  
{
    electricityUsed += value;    
}

      public int getElectricityUsed() 
      {
      return electricityUsed;
      }
}
```

**House**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class House 
    {

        ArrayList<Appliance> applianceList = new ArrayList<>();


        ElectricShower calleShower = new ElectricShower(1, 1, 1, 1);
        ElectricCooker calleCooker = new ElectricCooker(1, 1, 1, 1);


        public void addAppliance()
        {

          applianceList.add(calleShower);
          applianceList.add(calleCooker);


        }

        public void timePasses()
        {

            calleShower.timePasses();
            calleCooker.timePasses();

          //this method is called as part of the simulation to trigger a new fifteen minute period
          //in the house. When it is called, it will in turn call timePasses() on all the Appliances in the House.

        }  
    }

public class CourseworkTest {



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

  House callHouse = new House();
  callHouse.timePasses();

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Electric shower electricity consumption = 5
Electric cooker electricity consumption = 10
```

I've been working on this for hours and I just don't understand how the exact same code can somehow produce different results? I don't see how one can be `10` and other `5` when they do the exact same thing and go through the same process. Any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Another problem you have, which is hindering you understanding of your code, is you have duplication everywhere. Delete your subclasses of Appliance and just pass in different parameters to its constructor to create new appliance instance. Also delete the Meter class. It's unnecessary and complicating your code. Finally, there is no way this is the least code required to show the problem. Edit out everything unrelated (eg all unrelated fields and methods). Learning to use a debugger would also help.

Answer (score 2):

The `ElectricMeter` class is a singleton, meaning that one (same) instance will exist throughout the execution of your application.

First, from `ElectricShower.timePasses()`, you make the following call:

```
ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(5);
```

Then, you again make this call from `ElectricCooker.timePasses()`.  Hence, when you output the consumption the second time, it is being reported as `10`.

Using a singleton to represent the common shared electric meter for a house seems like a reasonable design decision.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for your feedback this makes sense now.